# Changing the side Panel content based on the logged in user type

Tags: angularjs

I have to make modifications to an already existing project such that the `side panel` data has to be dynamically changed based on the user **logged in**. At present in the `Index.html` the side panel page(home page) is hidden and included as part of all pagesand the controller for the index page is the side panel page controller and it is hidden incase the page is the "Login page" and for other pages using `ngview` we are dynamically getting web content based on the Url using `ngrouter`. Can anyone provide any pointers such that the login page is only present as part of index page and for other pages got using `ngview` how to make the side panel page as a common page.

Comment: can you add your code using jsfiddle? That will be easier to help u

Comment: Which angular version?